# Fixing error "Badly formed hexadecimal UUID string" after converting existing id to uuid in Django (Django 3.0)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, uuid, django-3.0

I created a table with an initial IntegerField primary key and later changed the id to a UUIDField. Now this raises a *"Badly formed hexadecimal UUID string"*, I guess because a number such as "1" isn't a valid UUID value. Does anyone know a concise way to fix this in code when updating the models.py file for the django app?

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, double check that you don't have any foreign key with Cascade uppon this model. Then, instead of changing the type of `id = models.IntegerField()` :

- create a new field `uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary=True)` (default will set the field for existing rows)
- make migrations
- remove the `id` field
- make migrations
- rename the `uuid` field to `id`
- make migrations
- migrate

However, you should know that removing the `id` field, and / or naming the `uuid` is not mandatory, and it's often a good idea to keep both.